# How can I programmatically enter a mode?

Tags: vorpal.js

I want to have normal `.command()` handler that does some async calls, then decides if it will output something or throw the user into a mode. Is that possible?

If yes, how cat I set the delimiter based on my async calls? Can I set a custom `.action()` function for this mode dynamically?

Alternatively, is it possible to pass a context to this dynamically created mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a second (or multiple) instance of Vorpal, with an entirely different set of commands. These could also be declared these on the fly.

By calling `vorpal.show()` on the new instance, this would "detach" the UI from the old Vorpal onto the new for the duration of that "mode", and it would appear to the user that you got an entirely new set of commands, delimiter, etc.

```
var modeA = new Vorpal().delimiter('fooland:');
var modeB = new Vorpal().delimiter('barland:');

modeA.command('foo'); // ...
modeB.command('bar'); // ...

// Only foo is present as a command.
modeA.show();
setTimeout(function(){
  // Now bar is present as a command instead.
  modeB.show();
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Maybe this works, but it doesn't solve the problem. Doing it would be the same as declaring a normal mode, doing work on `.init()` and then going to the mode, statically declared. Perhaps it is unclear, but the point of my desire to programmatically enter a mode is to be able to have set things inside it -- dynamic action handler, dynamic delimiter -- at the time the mode is called.

Comment: Ah. Something I've seen other people do is to create a second (or multiple) instance of Vorpal, with an entirely different set of commands (you could declare these on the fly), and then just call `vorpal.show()` on the new instance. This would "detach" the UI from the old Vorpal onto the new for the duration of that "mode", and it would appear to the user that you got an entirely new set of commands, delimiter, etc.. Did I understand you correctly this time?

Comment: Yes, and that's a fairly good solution. The documentation should mention this, because although it is there somehow, it's easy to miss this possibility -- which is a powerful one.

Comment: Great! I updated my answer to match this. I agree, it should be added to the wiki. I'll try to get to it, but feel free to add what you want as well. :)